# download jar file from j2me

Tags: java-me, jar, executable-jar

I need to download a jar file from server. I upload a jar file  to somewhere.net and try to download it through my device. But when I open it it does not open application rather it opens a file with special character. How can I open a apps jar file from remote server and open it as apps?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the MIME types have been configured on the server for the jad and jar file. If you are downloading the file, you also need to check that the MIDlet-Jar-URL property of the .jad file, points to the relative location of the jar file.